# Angular reactive forms and custom validator error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

In my Angular 4 app, I have a [custom form validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) that looks like this:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function myCustomValidator(myCustomArg: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

    if (control.value) {
      // do some checks with control.value and myCustomArg
      // return error if needed
    }

    // return null otherwise
    control.setErrors(null);
    return null;
  };
}
```

but when I try to use it in one of my [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'myControl': new FormControl(null, [ myCustomValidator(...) ]),
      // ...
    });
  }
```

I get several errors:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
>       at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.AbstractControl._updateControlsErrors (forms.es5.js:2836)
>       at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.AbstractControl.setErrors (forms.es5.js:2772)
>       at file-extension.validator.ts:17
>       at forms.es5.js:506
>       at Array.map ()
>       at _executeValidators (forms.es5.js:506)
>       at FormControl.validator (forms.es5.js:462)
>       at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.es5.js:2720)
>       at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.es5.js:2688)
>       at new FormControl (forms.es5.js:3011)

---

> ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: {…}, 
>   elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}

---

> ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

But unfortunately they are not very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related with the way the validator is assigned to the field.

In fact, the validator is trying to access to the control's value `control.value`.

But when the validator factory function is called, the control doesn't exist yet:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  'myControl': new FormControl(null, [ myCustomValidator(...) ]),
  // ...
});
```

So in order to solve the issue, just **create the form first** and **then** assign the validator:

```
ngOnInit() {
   // first create the form with its controls
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    'myControl': new FormControl(null),
    // ...
  });

  // then assign the custom validator
  this.form.get('myControl').setValidators([
    myCustomValidator(...),
  ]);
}
```